# Run k8s commands within Airflow hosted on an EKS cluster using the python api

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow, amazon-eks

I currently have an Airflow deployment hosted on an EKS cluster, and want it to run a report that will check the logging for another deployment and alert me if any errors have occurred.

Locally I'm able to run this without issue as I can just point the k8s python api to my kubeconfig, however this doesn't work once deployed as there isn't a $Home/.kube directory with the kubeconfig on the pod.

```
    with client.ApiClient(config.load_kube_config(config_file=k8s_config_file)) as api_client:
        api_instance = client.CoreV1Api(api_client)
```

I've tried removing the load_kube_config command, however this just throws a connection refused error, presumably because it now doesn't know about any cluster, although it resides in one...

I assume putting the kubeconfig on the deployment wouldn't be a good practice.

How can I get airflow to use the kubeconfig of the cluster it's hosted on?
Or is there an alternative I'm missing...

Comment: You could use a kubeconfig which matched a k8s user with limited permissions, rather than the one for the k8s cluster owner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering some concerns from the question:

> I've tried removing the load_kube_config command, however this just throws a connection refused error, presumably because it now doesn't know about any cluster, although it resides in one...

To run your code inside of the cluster (from a `Pod`) you will need to switch:

- **from:** `config.load_kube_config()`
- **to:** `config.load_incluster_config()`

Please read below as I addressed the rest of the setup needed to run Kubernetes Python API library code inside the cluster.

---

> How can I get airflow to use the kubeconfig of the cluster it's hosted on? Or is there an alternative I'm missing...

In fact there is a solution that you are missing:

**You will need to use a `ServiceAccount` with proper `Roles` and `RoleBindings`.**

Let me explain it a bit more and add an example to follow:

---

#### Explanation:

To run such setup as I described above you will need to refer to following Kubernetes docs:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Configure pod container: Configure service account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/)* - for `ServiceAccount`
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: Access authn authz: RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)* - for `Role` and `RoleBinding`

As stated in the official documentation:

> When you (a human) access the cluster (for example, using `kubectl`), you are authenticated by the apiserver as a particular User Account. Processes in containers inside pods can also contact the apiserver. **When they do, they are authenticated as a particular Service Account (for example, default)**.

You will need to add permissions to your `ServiceAccount` with `Roles` and `RoleBidings` to allow it to query the Kubernetes API server. For example you will need to add permissions to list `Pods`.

---

#### Example:

I've already answered quite lengthily a similar case on Serverfault. I encourage you to check it out:

- *[Serverfault.com: Starting a container on a Kubernetes cluster from another container](https://serverfault.com/questions/1041268/starting-a-container-on-a-kubernetes-cluster-from-another-container/1041787#1041787)*

I've allowed myself to copy and alter some of the parts of this answer:

> #### Create a `ServiceAccount`
>
> ```yaml
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: ServiceAccount
> metadata:
>   name: python-job-sa
> ```
>
> This `ServiceAccount` will be used with the `Deployment/Pod` that will host your Python code.
>
> #### Assign specific permissions to your `ServiceAccount`
>
> ```yaml
> apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
> kind: Role
> metadata:
>   namespace: default
>   name: python-job-role
> rules:
> # This will give you access to pods
> - apiGroups: [""]
>   resources: ["pods"]
>   verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
> # This will give you access to pods logs
> - apiGroups: [""]
>   resources: ["pods/log"]
>   verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
> ```
>
> This is a `Role` that allows to query the Kubernetes API for the resources like > `Pods`.
>
> #### Bind your `Role` to a `ServiceAccount`
>
> ```yaml
> apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
> kind: RoleBinding
> metadata:
>   name: python-job-rolebinding
>   namespace: default
> subjects:
> - kind: ServiceAccount
>   name: python-job-sa 
>   namespace: default
> roleRef:
>   kind: Role 
>   name: python-job-role
>   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
> ```

After applying those rules you can use the `serviceAccount: python-job-sa` in your `Deployment` manifest (in `.spec.template.spec`) and query Kubernetes API like below:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_incluster_config() # <-- IMPORTANT
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()

print("Listing pods with their IPs:")

ret = v1.list_namespaced_pod("default")
for i in ret.items:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
```

Output:

```sh
Listing pods with their IPs:
10.88.0.12  default nginx-deployment-d6bcfb88d-q8s8s
10.88.0.13  default nginx-deployment-d6bcfb88d-zbdm6
10.88.0.11  default cloud-sdk
```

---

Additonal resources:

- *[Blog.meain.io: Accessing Kubernetes API from pod](https://blog.meain.io/2019/accessing-kubernetes-api-from-pod/)*

Comment: Hi Dawid, thank you very much for your answer. I will try and implement that!